# Oracle Cloud Instance SSH connectivity issue

Tags: ssh, cloud, openssh, ssh-tunnel, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I was using OCI Instance for almost 3 months, From today i was unable to connect with the instance,
Shows Server timed out Error(ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection timed out).

I already tried resetting the VCN Settings & Even Created a new Instance with old boot volume.Still this does'nt fix the problem.

If Anybody know a solution please reply.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like issue was with the boot volume. Try this steps below:

1. Created a new instance with new boot volume
2. Attached old boot volume as block volume (to retrieve previous instance data)

Hope it will be helpful for someone in future.